# What's the appropiate file structure of a project?

Tags: c++

I am new to OOP/C++. I have three files: main.cpp, matrix.cpp and matrix.h. I am getting errors all the time, it sasys

error C2653: 'matrix' : is not a class or namespace name

error C2065: 'tomb' : undeclared identifier

main.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "matrix.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    matrix m;
    return 0;
}
```

matrix.h:

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H
class matrix{

private:
    int tomb[3][3];

public:
    matrix(); //default konstruktor


};

#endif
```

matrix.cpp

```
#include "matrix.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

matrix::matrix(){
    unsigned int x=0, y=0;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<9; i++){
        std::cout << "Kerem a(z) " << i << ". szamot" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> matrix::tomb[x][y];
        if(y<2) y++;
        else{
            y =0;
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `#include "stdafx.h"` needs to be the very first directive if you're using precompiled headers.  Everything before it is ignored.

Comment: @PeterHuene Out of curiosity, do you know the reasoning behind that?

Comment: I was never on the compiler team, so I unfortunately do not.

Comment: @user2351645: Note that you're writing out of tomb's bounds when x >= 3, too.  Probably better to have a loop going from (0, 2] for x and an inner loop going from (0, 2] for y (with some symbolic representation of "max dimension" shared between tomb's declaration and these loops).  Also, you should look into using std::vector or std:array.

Comment: Thank you! I'm working on it! :)

Comment: @EricFinn: of course, I suspect that it ignores everything before the include of stdafx.h because any changes to preprocessor state could affect the .pch. It's probable that the compiler team never felt compelled to at least check if there are any non-comment tokens before the include and error if there are, instead of silently ignoring them.

Comment: @Peter I'm pretty sure that MSVC *does* issue a diagnostic if it finds non-comment tokens before the precompiled header is included: [warning C4627](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531441.aspx)